# How to invoke a python script to run without a server and produce a csv file as an output using Power Apps or Power Automate?

Tags: python, powerbi, powerapps, power-automate-desktop

I am a beginner and doing the very first project in Power Automate, Power Apps and Power BI, so I will request you to kindly help me. My task is this -

1. I am provided an excel file called source.xlsx which i kept in my local folder called Dev.
2. I have written a python script (present in Dev folder) called generate.py.
3. This script reads data from source.xlsx, does required work and generates a new pandas dataframe "dfOutput". I store dfOutput in a csv file called output.csv (present in Dev folder).

Code Snippets from generate.py-

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def formatUtilityFunction(value):
   value = value.replace('.', 0)
   value = value.replace('', 0)
   return value


#main

df = pd.read_excel("source.xlsx",sheet_name="Input1",header=1,usecols=['Quantity','PurchaseDate','CostPrice','SellPrice'])

df[['CostPrice','SellPrice']]=df[['CostPrice','SellPrice']].apply(formatUtilityFunction)

# more code to generate a new dataset by reading data from df and doing further work

dfOutput=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=[,'MonthYear','MonthlyCP','MonthlySP'])

dfOutput.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```

4. I load output.csv into Power BI and create bar graph.

My roadblocks-

As-Is:
I am manually running generate.py to produce output.csv and I manually load that into Power BI.

To-Be:

1. The python script needs to be automatically triggered to regenerate output.csv whenever some change is noted in source.xlsx.
2. Also, the graph in Power BI needs to be updated automatically if output.csv changes.
3. BIGGEST CONCERN : I am not allowed to use any server or cloud for hosting the python script, in the final project.(Currently its running in my own computer)

So my concerns -

1. where will my Python script run
2. where will it store the output.csv file
3. how will I build the entire dataflow?

I can use only Power Apps, Power Automate, Power BI.

I can find from sources that Power Automate has a capability of running very simple Python 2 scripts (I am using Python 3 , pandas, numpy )and stores some simple output in a variable, not csv file.

Do I really need to use Power Automate or Power Apps or only Power BI can tackle the requirements on its own?

If I need to use Power Automate or Power apps, how will I implement the requirements?

I am a novice and getting extremely overwhelmed.

Kindly help. Please.